# Secure File Storage

Tags: file-compression, file-converter, data-transfer, zip, secure

I have some file I want to store that I do not want to be readable with out proper software or conversion. I used to ZIP file until Windows 7 Started to scan the zip file and "Remove Viruses". The Files contain Sensitive Data that Only I should be able to read. How Would I Accomplish This?

Comment: You can protect your ZIP files with a password.

Comment: Virus scanners can easily still "scan" the files inside

Comment: @epicdig07 They can **not**. They can often see the file names, but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TrueCrypt (deprecated), or the newer VeraCrypt (which is based on TrueCrypt).

Answer (score -1):

Might find this useful

https://medium.com/internxt/alternative-to-dropbox-f3d242648497

https://medium.com/internxt/alternative-to-cryptomator-217310e9e715

https://medium.com/internxt/alternative-to-sync-30a64c3c5e0e

I found Internxt to be quite secure. Sync and pCloud are other alternatives